# console.log num-1 is working but "disp"+num-1 is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nan

When i tried to run this code in javascript

```
 var num = 3;
 console.log(num-1);
```

it worked fine. But whenever I try to run this one

```
var num = 3;
console.log("ans "+num-1);
```

the output is NaN. 
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with brackets

```js
var num = 3;
console.log("ans " + (num - 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

By grouping the `num-1` part with parentheses:

```
var num = 3;
console.log("ans " + (num - 1));
// ------------------^-------^
```

The reason you got `NaN` is that `"ans " + num - 1` is `("ans " + num) - 1`, and the `-` operator coerces both operands to number. `"ans 3"` can't be coerced to number, so you get `NaN`, and all math operations with `NaN` result in `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to add string and integer value,

Try using this

```js
var num = 3;
console.log("ans ",num-1);
```

Comment: That works for `console.log`, but doesn't address the general case.